# How do I multiply a column in predefined increments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a pandas df with integers (value) in one column. I need to make a second column that equals 0 when the value is < 100, 1.00 when the value >= 100, and add 0.25 for every 25 increase in value and vice versa if value decreases. BUT I only want to add 0.25 to the new column up to value 2.00, i.e max four times.

Expected outcome 'size' :

```
value   size
90          0.00
100         1.00 
110         1.00 
115         1.00 
125         1.25 
145         1.25 
150         1.50 
175         1.75 
195         1.75 
200         2.00 
230         2.00 
250         2.00 
200         2.00 
180         1.75 
150         1.50 
135         1.25 
120         1.00 
109         1.00 
99          0.00
```

Any advice would be most welcome!

Comment: Is `size` supposed to be the expected outcome? Please show your efforts, this solution is a little involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `//` (integer division):

```
In [11]: (df.value // 25) * 0.25
Out[11]:
0     0.75
1     1.00
2     1.00
3     1.00
4     1.25
5     1.25
6     1.50
7     1.75
8     1.75
9     2.00
10    2.25
11    2.50
12    2.00
13    1.75
14    1.50
15    1.25
16    1.00
17    1.00
18    0.75
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

which gets you most of the way there, except for the <100 condition:

```
In [12]: (df.value >= 100) * ((df.value // 25) * 0.25)
Out[12]:
0     0.00
1     1.00
2     1.00
3     1.00
4     1.25
5     1.25
6     1.50
7     1.75
8     1.75
9     2.00
10    2.25
11    2.50
12    2.00
13    1.75
14    1.50
15    1.25
16    1.00
17    1.00
18    0.00
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

and then clip the ones over 2:

```
In [13]: (df.value >= 100) * ((df.value // 25) * 0.25).clip(0, 2)
Out[13]:
0     0.00
1     1.00
2     1.00
3     1.00
4     1.25
5     1.25
6     1.50
7     1.75
8     1.75
9     2.00
10    2.00
11    2.00
12    2.00
13    1.75
14    1.50
15    1.25
16    1.00
17    1.00
18    0.00
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: maybe `df.value.clip(100, 200) // 25 * 0.25`?

Comment: @MaxU eep, yeah, quite a bit going on there (I had thought originally it was just `//`!)

Answer (score 1):

By using `pd.cut`

```
R=list(range(100, 225,25))
R=[0]+R+[np.inf]
label=[0]+list(np.arange(1.0,2.25,0.25))
pd.cut(df.value,R,labels=label,right=False)

Out[16]: 
0     0.00
1     1.00
2     1.00
3     1.00
4     1.25
5     1.25
6     1.50
7     1.75
8     1.75
9     2.00
10    2.00
11    2.00
12    2.00
13    1.75
14    1.50
15    1.25
16    1.00
17    1.00
18    0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution very similar to [@Andy Hayden's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46797240/5741205):

```
In [80]: df['size'] = df['value'].clip(100, 200) // 25 * 0.25

In [81]: df
Out[81]:
    value  size
0      90  1.00
1     100  1.00
2     110  1.00
3     115  1.00
4     125  1.25
5     145  1.25
6     150  1.50
7     175  1.75
8     195  1.75
9     200  2.00
10    230  2.00
11    250  2.00
12    200  2.00
13    180  1.75
14    150  1.50
15    135  1.25
16    120  1.00
17    109  1.00
18     99  1.00
```

Comment: @cJc but this is wrong! I doesn't set the ones less than 99 to 0!!

Comment: @AndyHayden, yep, I missed that part, thank you! I’ll try to fix it when I’m back at PC.

Comment: @AndyHayden You are absolutely right, I did not have the possibility to actually try this until now. Thanks for helping and pointing this out.